# LaTeX in titles

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles

Recently I edited a question adding LaTeX formatting for chemical formulas. I edited the both the text and the title, and this edit were accepted by peer-review. After some time, I noticed that another user (with high reputation) edited the question, eliminating LaTeX formatting from the title (with the comment *NO LATEX IN TITLEZ!*).

**Why LaTeX formatting shouldn't be used in titles?**

I think that titles, as the text, should be clean and clearly written and using LaTeX formatting will help to achieve this goal.

Comment: :) That user's edit message was a bit more elegant, and in all-caps. ;)

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Now is fixed! ; )

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Was Ina ‘that user’? xD

Comment: @Jan I'll leave the users to decide whether if that user was Ina or MAR.

Comment: Thanks for the badge, R.M. \*___\*